# How to crawl multiple keywords with python icrawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I have an array with a lot of keywords:

```
array = ['table', 'chair', 'pen']
```

I want to crawl 5 images from Google Image Search for each item in my `array` with python `icrawler`

Here is the initialization:

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler

google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(
  parser_threads=2, 
  downloader_threads=4,
  storage={ 'root_dir': 'images' }
)
```

I use a loop to crawl each item:

```
for item in array:
  google_crawler.crawl(
    keyword=item, 
    offset=0, 
    max_num=5,
    min_size=(500, 500)
  )
```

However, I get the error log:

```
  File "crawler.py", line 20, in <module>
    min_size=(500, 500)
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/pak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/icrawler/builtin/google.py", line 83, in crawl
    feeder_kwargs=feeder_kwargs, downloader_kwargs=downloader_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/pak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/icrawler/crawler.py", line 166, in crawl
    self.feeder.start(**feeder_kwargs)                                   
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/pak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/icrawler/utils/thread_pool.py", line 66, in start
    worker.start()                                                       
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/pak/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 842, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

which seems that I cannot use `google_crawler.crawl` more than once. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version, you can use it like this.

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler

google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(
    parser_threads=2,
    downloader_threads=4,
    storage={'root_dir': 'images'}
)

for keyword in ['cat', 'dog']:
    google_crawler.crawl(
        keyword=keyword, max_num=5, min_size=(500, 500), file_idx_offset='auto')
    # set `file_idx_offset` to 'auto' will prevent naming the 5 images
    # of dog from 000001.jpg to 000005.jpg, but naming it from 000006.jpg.
```

or if you want to download these images to different folders, you can simply create two `GoogleImageCrawler` instances.

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler

for keyword in ['cat', 'dog']:
    google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(
        parser_threads=2,
        downloader_threads=4,
        storage={'root_dir': 'images/{}'.format(keword)}
    )
    google_crawler.crawl(
        keyword=keyword, max_num=5, min_size=(500, 500))
```

Comment: ps: You can raise an issue on Github for quicker responses.